# Error 0x80240024 while trying to download Paint 3D Preview

Tags: windows-10, windows-insider, paint-3d-preview

I have signed up for the insider program. When I go to the store, I am able to search for Paint 3D Preview. However, when I try to download it by pressing the `Get` button in the store, it gives the following error:

[image: paint 3d preview error]

Same result when I try to initiate the download from the following URL instead:
[Paint 3D Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/mspaint/9nblggh5fv99)

This is the build of Windows I am using:

[image: windows version]

What does this error mean and how can I install this?

Comment: "I have signed up for the insider program."  Ok, but which build of Windows 10 are you currently using?  Greater than 14800?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I am running Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.321). I have added this to the question as well now. Requirements on the app store page says that it needs `10042.0 or higher` as per screenshot I have posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> I am running Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.321).

In the description of Paint 3D Preview, it says:

> The application required joining the Windows Insider Program *and installing the latest Windows Insiders build (**Build 14800 or greater**)*.

So, as it suggests, you need to update your Windows to the latest Insider build, which should (currently) be at least build 14800.

> Requirements on the app store page says that it needs 10042.0 or higher

When submitting an app to the Store the "requirements" selection only includes certain build numbers to select from.  So they probably chose the highest one they could but, as noted above, put extra instruction/specifics in the Description (in the same place they say that you need to belong to the Insider Program).

Comment: The list system requirements, for this application are clearly wrong, 10042 isn't even the RTM build.  @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 correctly points out, the real problem, you must be running the current Insider Preview build.  Since the application, was annouced to be a feature of the Creators Update, you won't be able to install it on any build before that annoucement was made (i.e. build 4800 or greater).